# AngularJS. Правильное использование сервисов

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В стайл-гайде по Ангуляру от Тода Мотто есть пример использования сервиса в контроллере **"Presentational logic only (MVVM)"**:

```
// recommended
function MainCtrl (UserService) {

  var vm = this;

  UserService
    .getUsers()
    .then(function (response) {
      vm.users = response;
    });

  vm.removeUser = function (user, index) {
    UserService
      .removeUser(user)
      .then(function (response) {
        vm.users.splice(index, 1);
      });
  };

}
```

Я давно подозревал, что делаю что-то крайне не модно, т.к. мои фабрики настолько автономны, что контроллер остается почти без работы. Использую фабрики так:

```
function UserService () {

  var api = {
    loaded: false

    getData: getData
  }

  return api;

  function getData() {

    // Получение данных

    api.loaded = true;
  }
}

function MainCtrl (UserService) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.userService = UserService;

  // Использую api фабрики в контроллере, если нужно получить некие входные данные
  UserService.getData()

}
```

Дальше работаю с фабрикой напрямую в шаблоне, вызывая нужные методы в директивах(ng-click, ng-mouseover, ng-hide, ...)
То есть получается просто пробрасываю фабрику во view через контроллер.

Помогите культивировать в мозгу логику по которой нужно отделять работу фабрики от работы контроллера.

Comment: например тестирование

Answer (score 2):

Попробую объяснить:

*Контроллеры* предназначены для обрабатывания событий от пользователя (*[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), и других ng директив, весь список [здесь](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng)* ).
*Фабрики* или сервисы [синглтоны](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))(а чем они отличаются читать [тут](http://onedev.net/post/334)) , которые предназначены для получения необходимых данных с БД и кукисов, или же мы сами можем сохранять в них необходимые данные, чтобы потом использовать их по нашему усмотрению.

Ангуляр это MVW(*Model-View-Whatever*) фреймворк, это означает, что мы можем использовать и MVC и MVVM паттерны([статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/215605/)). Но структуру работы буду объяснять по MVC.

Основная схема:
*Контроллер* получает событие от пользователя, потом берет нам необходимые данные с *Фабрики*, сохраняет все эти данные в **$scope**
контроллера, и после чего отображает все это в *View*.

Comment: Не похоже на законченное объяснение :)
"Контроллеры предназначены для обрабатывания событий от пользователя" - это только малая доля того, что могут делать контроллеры.
"а чем они отличаются читать тут" - я об этом не спрашивал )
"берет нам необходимые данные с Фабрики, сохраняет все эти данные в $scope контроллера" - это большая ошибка - сохранять все данные с фабрики в $scope. В скоп хранится только то, что должно быть обновляемо вотчером, в ином случае при большом количестве данных дигест-цикл взорвется. Как правило, данные хранят this контроллера.

Comment: @Harvey, _В скоп хранится только то, что должно быть обновляемо вотчером_ - вы не правы. нет никакой связи между тем что хранится в скопе и что будет проверяться наблюдателем. _Как правило, данные хранят this контроллера._ - ссылка на который при использовании _controllerAs_ синтаксиса, так же помещается в скоп

Comment: @Grundy, согласен, упустил.

Answer (score 1):

В **контроллер** помещается логика куска приложения которая относится только к данному контроллеру.
В **сервис-фабрику** помещаются методы, данные которые не содержат логики, а возвращают примерно всегда одни и те же данные и могут использоваться (вызываться) в любой части приложения.
Обычно сервис инжектится в контроллер,

1. из сервиса получаются нужные данные,
2. в зависимости от принятого в приложении подхода эти данные записываются либо в св-во скоупа либо в св-во контроллера (Controller As syntax).
3. И только потом к ним можно обратиться из шаблона.